# modify something in several specific files for exemple txt (bash)

Tags: bash

I want to write something in several file,
I tried with a find :

```
find . -name "*.txt" |
```

but i don't know what can i write after the pipe.

I also tried with a "for" :

```
for element in * 
do
    if [[ $element = '*.txt' ]]
    then
        echo "cc" > $element
    fi
done
```

but my if is wrong,

if someone could help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the glob pattern with the `.txt` suffix in `for`:

```
for i in *.txt; do
    # if there are no matching files, break
    [ -f "$i" ] || break
    echo "cc" > "$i"
done
```